# why use string constructor with char array for constants?

Tags: c#, .net

I found this piece of code and I'd like to understand why the developer used the string constructor with a char array instead of just a literal constant string:

```
static string atomLang = new String("lang".ToCharArray());
```

Comment: to avoid pooling of the string?

Comment: Maybe he was trying to make the code more interesting :)). I am sorry about that, but I couldn't resist saying the joke.

Comment: It's probably because, if you want to initialize it with a string, you can just put `static string atomLang = "lang"`.  If you already have a string, why use `new`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is to avoid getting a reference to the [interned instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx) of the string.

```
string str1 = "lang";
string str2 = "lang";
string str3 = new String("lang".ToCharArray());

Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(str1, str2));   // Output: true
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(str1, str3));   // Output: false
```

Not that this will have any practical effects on your code (other than marginal performance differences).

Comment: It should be made clear that this will have a *negative* effect on performance, if any.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Yes, definitely. Although I suspect there might be rare cases where it might have a positive effect, due to avoiding contention on the same string when shared among multiple cores.

Comment: @Douglas, the same string accesses by multiple cores results in shared cache lines which is not harmful. CPUs can share read-only cache lines.

Comment: @usr: Yes, the sources I read indicated that memory contention would only occur for writes. Thanks for confirming!